# post to url masking the query

Tags: javascript, php, post, get, masking

I have a script that post variables and gets them, problem is the URL of the page includes the variables.

Is there a way to hide the variables in the url.

for example the url get shown as

```
http://localhost/try.php?js_var=123abc
```

Is there a way to change the code to print

```
http://localhost/try.php
```

**the javascript and html**

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="link">Click me!</a>

<script>
    var js_var = "123abc";

    document.getElementById("link").onclick = function (e)

    {
        window.location = "try.php?js_var=" + js_var;


    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**try.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['js_var'])) $php_var = $_GET['js_var'];
else $php_var = "<br />js_var is not set!";

echo $php_var;
?>
```

Comment: you sure this " window.location = "try.php?js_var=" + js_var;" is a POST?

Comment: `GET` requests will always display the query string in the url. If you'd like to hide it, add it to a `<input type="hidden" />` field in a form and use the `POST` method...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way of hiding the variables, but you could use `POST` method and `form` tag. Some info on GET vs POST - http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: window.location = "try.php?js_var=" + js_var; !== POST

Comment: and also you could use $.post() or $.ajax() with post method